# Is there any easy methods to convert from ASCII to UTF8? (using boost::locale)

Tags: c++, boost, utf-8, locale

I'm trying convert some strings from ASCII to UTF8.

And, i searched many things, but i can't found it.

So i coded this.

```
std::string ASCII("ASCII string");
auto utf8 = boost::locale::conv::to_utf<char>(ansi, std::locale("en_US.UTF8"));
```

Is this right? on my system this is dosen't work.

Please, help me.

Thanks.

Comment: If by "ansi" you mean ASCII, then it is a strict subset of UTF-8. As such, no conversion is required.

Comment: What do you mean "from ansi"? ANSI encoding can mean a lot of different things.

Comment: @usta Yes, it is mean ASCII. i'm sorry. but conversion is required, if ASCII string is another language, it is need to convert

Comment: @Simple It means ASCII, I'm sorry, I do not know well

Comment: @PengChat: If by "ANSI" you mean "ASCII", then no conversion is required.  UTF-8 represents code points U+0000 through U+007F (inclusive) (i.e. ASCII) exactly the same way as ASCII does.  If there are code points outside this range, then you're not dealing with ASCII, and you should elaborate.

Comment: @Lee ASCII cannot be "another language" - it is strictly [this set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII_Code_Chart-Quick_ref_card.jpg) of characters, nothing more, nothing less. Now it is clear what you wanted to do instead, and I'm glad you now have a working solution.

Comment: @usta Thanks a lot. Now i have a working solution :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you mean conversion from your system locale to utf8 or vice versa, we use the following which is working well:

```
static std::string fromLocale(const std::string &localeStr){
    boost::locale::generator g;
    g.locale_cache_enabled(true);
    std::locale loc = g(boost::locale::util::get_system_locale());
    return boost::locale::conv::to_utf<char>(localeStr,loc);
}

static std::string toLocale(const std::string &utf8Str){
    boost::locale::generator g;
    g.locale_cache_enabled(true);
    std::locale loc = g(boost::locale::util::get_system_locale());
    return boost::locale::conv::from_utf<char>(utf8Str,loc);
}
```

Comment: Great answer, exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: Which version of boost was this written against?